# Invoke VSCode Extension from outside VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, power-platform

I'm trying to run Microsoft Power Platform CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/cli/introduction commands on a linux build agent for CI/CD puposes. This CLI is only available for linux as a VSCode extension. Example usage of the CLI: `pac help`.

I've installed VSCode on the build agent and the Power Platform extension with the following commands:

`tar -xzf code-stable-x64-1675266941.tar.gz`

`code --install-extension microsoft-IsvExpTools.powerplatform-vscode-1.1.16.vsix`

These command run successfully, but I receive "command not found" when running `pac help`. This was somewhat expected as I'm not running the command from the Integrated terminal in VSCode.

Is there a way to invoke the extension and run these commands without opening VSCode? I have the vsix file downloaded onto the build agent.

Answer (score 0):

vscode extension's `.vsix` file is just a zip file, just

1. `unzip microsoft-IsvExpTools.powerplatform-vscode-1.1.16.vsix`
2. `cd` into the folder
3. run the command, `pac help`

Comment: how is this different than what the asker said they already tried?

Comment: no need to install vscode or its extension at all, i recommended unzip and cd into the extract folder and run that command directly or asker can add that folder in PATH and run it anywhere

Comment: did i misunderstand the question? asker has a tool that comes as vscode extension, and question was how to run that tool inside the vsix file without vscode.
the answer i provided are steps doing that

Comment: if you think there's a executable search / pathing issue, then it would help for yo to spell that out.